# How many days do you need (minimum) to visit Oslo and others?

Tags: europe, norway, luggage-storage, oslo

I will be visiting Norway the next August and due my route (I will be travelling around the country) I have doubts about visiting Oslo half and a day or just half day (about 5-6 hours).

I have read in many blogs that Oslo is not the most beautiful city of Norway by far, but as I have not visited yet I don't know if is truth or not.

I will be also visiting Stavanger and Bergen. What about them? How many days I need?

Besides that I would like to know if there is any luggage storage is Olso

Comment: Without knowing what you are interested in, scenery, art, museums, ships, ..., this is almost impossible to answer.

Comment: Well I would like to know how much time do you need to get a general known of the city, without going into detail, I mean, without visiting museums, etc. But Is part of the question, if somebody tell me that it's "mandatory" go to some museum, I will try to go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the size of the 2 cities, I'd say 1.5 day and 2 nights for Bergen and Stavanger.

For Oslo, I would put in at 3 days (4 nights) as it is a bigger city with more to see in general.

I like the NY Times "36 hours in" series; it kind of boils down what to see/eat/drink in short time in a city.

https://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/16/travel/36-hours-in-oslo.html

https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/06/29/travel/what-to-do-36-hours-in-bergen-norway.html

related:

http://www.thetravelmagazine.net/48-hours-stavanger-norway.html

I also suggest spending some time looking at the city's tourism web sites.

Comment: thx! It is just what i'm looking for!